# Memory cleanup issue converting QString to char* for use with a 3rd party library, how to solve?

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks

I am using a 3rd party library with Qt that requires `char*` strings. I am using the following code to convert my QString to a `char*`

```
char* toCharArray(const QString &string)
{
    QByteArray bytes = string.toLocal8Bit();
    char* data = new char[bytes.count() + 1];
    strcpy(data, bytes.data());
    return data;
}

// later on...

3rdPartyObject->3rdPartyMethod(toCharArray("someFile"));
```

What can I do to make sure the `char*` I return is cleaned up, apart from doing something messy like this?

```
char* path = toCharArray("someFile");
3rdPartyObject->3rdPartyMethod(path); // The class and method called can differ
delete[] path;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not just use

```
QString s;
3rdPartyObject->3rdPartyMethod( s.toLocal8Bit().data() );
```

The destruction of the temporary QByteArray at the end of the statement will clean up all the resources.

Comment: Thanks. This actually does work... something I read elsewhere led me to believe it would not. Guess I should stay on Stack Overflow. :)

Comment: even better: use constData() where possible (where the function takes const char*). Saves the extra detach (data() might copy the data unnecessarily internally)

Comment: @Frank - absolutely. I was just matching the OPs required type, +1

Comment: @Frank I did. ;) `const` isn't part of the actual data type so I didn't include it in my question since it wasn't relevant. +1 for any Googlers that see your comment, though.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, 'elsewhere' refers to the official Qt docs: http://developer.qt.nokia.com/faq/answer/how_can_i_convert_a_qstring_to_char_and_vice_versa, which say "`const char *c_str2 = str2.toLatin1().data();` will make the application crash as the QByteArray has not been stored and hence no longer exists"... I wasn't thinking and should have known this *would* work in my particular situation based on the rules of C++...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a smart pointer such as [boost::shared_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm?sess=00d05f2890eeb61f3ea7024b811ea31b) or  [std::auto_ptr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/memory/auto_ptr/) so that the memory is automatically deleted when the smart pointer goes out of scope.